# Send thousands of lines one-by-one to a socket server with NCat?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, performance-testing, netcat

I have a PHP socket server which I need to do some performance meassurements on to see how many connections it can handle. For this I thought of using [NCat](http://nmap.org/ncat/) but I don't have any preference for using it so please suggest others if they are any better suited for my need. I both have a Windows and Linux/CentOS client so a `bash` shell script would also be fine.

What I want to archieve is to connect to my socket server at port `tcp:10000`. This will initate a new fork on my server where it will process all data within this connection. Then the client should send X lines of text but each line much be followed by a couple of seconds of sleep before sending the next line. I want then to startup Y instances of this approach and somewhere I should reach the limit for when my server cannot handle anymore connections.

One line of text I want to send could for example be:

`93945[,015539,a3045538,0023,6926b.1,,9,9119,6,1,0,,,801,100,0,0,01,,21y18`

My problem is that I can't figure out how to do this with NCat!? My knowledge with NCat stops after being able to do this:

`echo FooBar | ncat 192.168.1.10 10000`

.. and this is only one line in its own connection.

Comment: See this answer, [Send a binary file (line by line) to a socket server with Netcat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19303690/2028935)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try JMeter. JMeter has an inherent support to TCP. It will take you 40 minutes to master it ..
http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: I don't have any X environment or Java on my Linux. Furthermore it looks quite like an overkill for my very simple task and I don't want to setup a big installation or use hours of getting to know the framework.