# Netcat to run subsequent command after connecting server via shell script in unix

Tags: bash, unix, netcat

I am fresh programmer on shell script. i want to do some automation using nc command via shell scripting. 
I need to run certain command after connecting server with selected port using nc . server is listening on connected port. we can get prompt to pass content while running from terminal. but i need to pass content many times. So I made a shell file which is containing  following code but response is not coming

```
#!/bin/bash  
#test.sh
```

`function nc_input {` 
 `echo "ABCD,R,1,5151670,512173140137353,01141456843,0"`
 }

`nc_input | nc 10.200.16.223 7913`

Comment: If you declare a function on one line, you must put a semi-colon at the end before the closing brace.

Comment: Where's the server-side code?

Comment: server is listening on 7913 port. i can pass the content after running nc command from  terminal manually. but i want to do automatically through shell script..

Comment: Did you add the semicolon mentioned in my first comment? Have you tried changing the first line to `#!/bin/bash -xv` so you can see what is happening? Is the script running at all?

Comment: I got some solution from below link. but I could to solve my requirement

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265300/send-a-binary-file-line-by-line-to-a-socket-server-with-netcat